# $\overline{V(I)-V(J)}=V(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I\colon J^n)$

Tags: commutative-algebra

Is it true that $\overline{V(I)-V(J)}=V\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I\colon J^n\right)$? If not, is it true for noetherian rings?

Comment: I think it is true for noetherian case, we can supppse $I=0$, and $J$ finitely generated, and reduce to the case of hypersurface. But I don't know about the non noetherian case.., but if the union of closure of $D(f_i)$ is closed, the same argument follows, but I doubt if it is true?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $I,J$ are ideals of a commutative ring $R$?

After replacing $R$ by $R/I$ we may clearly assume that $I=0$, so that $0:J^n=\mathrm{Ann}(J^n)$.

Let $I \subseteq R$ be an ideal. Then the following are equivalent:

$\overline{\mathrm{Spec}(R) \setminus V(J)} \subseteq V(I)\\
\mathrm{Spec}(R) \setminus V(J) \subseteq V(I)\\
V(J) \cup V(I)=\mathrm{Spec}(R)\\
IJ \subseteq \sqrt{0}\\I \subseteq (\sqrt{0}:J) \\
V(\sqrt{0}:J) \subseteq V(I)$

We have used here that $(\sqrt{0}:J)$ is a radical ideal, which is easy to prove. This proves
 $$\overline{\mathrm{Spec}(R) \setminus V(J)} = V\bigl((\sqrt{0}:J)\bigr)$$

We always have $(\sqrt{0}:J) \supseteq \sqrt{\bigcup_{n \geq 1} \mathrm{Ann}(J^n)}$, and the converse inclusion holds when $J$ is finitely generated (this is easy to check). In general we won't have equality.

Comment: Maybe in general we still have equality: suppose an element $x$ is in the intersection of ideals, we have to show $x$ is in the radical of the right hand side, otherwise, suppose $\mathcal{M}$ to be the set of ideals with $x^mJ^n$ not contained in $D$, since $I$ is in $\mathcal{M}$, $\mathcal{M}$ is non empty,we can show maximal elements are prime by definition of a prime ideal, which contracdicts the choice of $x$.I friend of mine told me about this.